# Lemmatisation for telugu words in python

Tags: nltk, translation, lemmatization

I am new to translation concepts and nltk. Do we have any stemmers or lemmatizers implemented in python for Telugu? Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try or find yourself already?

Comment: I read about the Porter stemmer, snowball stemmer. I have seen how stemmer for Hindi is implemented
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007558/is-there-is-any-stemmer-available-for-indian-language.
Now Can I implement the Telugu stemmer in a similar way by changing the suffixes mentioned?